# Como alinhar itens de UL na mesma linha?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

O slider nesse link: http://azaz.com.br/blog/ estava com os indicadores (itens da UL) alinhados, mas quando configuerei para ficar dinamico com wordpress, adicionando as template tags (codigo abaixo), elas desalinharam, ficando uma acima da outra.

```
<?php 

                    $posts_slides = new WP_Query (array(

                        'category_name' => 'Destaques',
                        'posts_per_page' => 3
                    ));

                    $n = 0;
                    while($posts_slides->have_posts()) : $posts_slides->the_post();

                    ?>


                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $n ?>">
                        <a href="#">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>


                </ul>

                <?php $n++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Ja busquei inspecionar todos os elementos tentando obter uma solução em CSS e não encontrei. Pode ser que com olhos diferentes a solução seja encontrada. Agradeço desde já a ajuda de vcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erro 1. 
Você esta repetindo a ul no seu loop.

- Solução. Repita só a `li` no seu loop

Erro 2.
Está usando `diplay: table` no css.

- Solução: Você pode usar, `diplay: inline` 
  ou `flexbox`pra resolver esse problema.